How can I reload or stop the nbd-server?
I'm running nbd-server on Debian (nbd-server package) with my config at /etc/nbd-server/config, but then I might change the config and need to reload. How can I do that?

man nbd-server has nothing on this

All I can use is kill PID and killall nbd-server to stop or restart it. There must be a command like nbd-server --reload or somehting.
What is the right way to do this to reload the ndb-server config after making changes?
What is the right way to stop the nbd-server if I don't want it running anymore?

How is it started? As a systemd service?

@vidarlo No, it can't start as a system service without creating my own .service file. It starts with the simple command nbd-server, and that's it. (Seems strange IYAM, but dems da berries.)

No, it's not strange, just a useful clarification that should be added to the question :)

@vidarlo Thanks, and with respect, every other -server command or server program I know is run with systemctl but this, so I at least do find it strange. Anyone who knows the answer about nbd-server commands would know how it starts, so I didn't put it in the question so as to be concise. Feel free to edit tho and I'll leave it.

Welcome, which distribution is used? how does the package was installed? most program aceept kill --hup for reloading

@djdomi nbd-server for Debian; added to Q.

In my version of the nbd-server man page, it says in the "DESCRIPTION" section:

While nbd-server is running, new exports can be added by re-writing configuration files and then sending SIGHUP to nbd-server. SIGHUP causes nbd-server to re-read its configuration files and to start serving all new exports which were not served earlier. Reconfiguration does not modify any existing export, it only appends new ones.

You can see this online here.
You can send SIGHUP to nbd-server using the kill command:
kill -HUP <ndb-server pid>

You can try signalling it by name, using either killall or pkill...
killall -HUP nbd-server

Or:
pkill -HUP nbd-server

...but note that there is an additional nbd-server process for every active connection, and I'm not sure how these processes respond to SIGHUP. A better option is just to configure a systemd unit for the service and then use systemctl reload nbd-server, and let systemd worry about keeping track of the main pid.

Update:  It looks like the version of nbd-server in Debian stable (3.24) is buggy. Sending SIGHUP to the nbd-server process causes it to fail with an invalid pointer error:
root@1f457c3e03fd:/etc/nbd-server/conf.d# nbd-server -d
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)

If you upgrade to the version in sid (3.26.1), it behaves as expected: sending SIGHUP to the process causes it to load any new configuration files, but does not impact existing clients. The server continues to run instead of crashing.

Yup, the Ubuntu docs. So, it should be nbd-server SIGHUP you're saying? How about turning it off?

To send a signal to a process you use the kill command: kill -HUP <pid of nbd-server>, or killall -HUP nbd-server. I would write a systemd unit for it and arrange for systemctl reload to do the work. I'm not sure what you mean by "turning it off"; do you mean, "how do I stop nbd-server?" (the answer would, again, be kill).

It only works if I nbd-client -d disconnect every device from the client machine first. WIthout that kill -HUP $(pgrep nbd-server) does not result in anything good. No matter how I kill or killall the nbd-server process, the client can't find it again unless I either properly -d disconnect each nbd or else I must then reboot the client. So, there is no graceful way to do this without all clients disconnecting first?

See my update, which I think identifies the root cause of your issue.

Okay, so if I understand correctly, it's back to the issue with Debian and Ubuntu using older repos; to solve it without too many mods, do it on Arch. :/ Thank you, correct answer for now. But, I would like one command example in your answer. Please feel free to change my edit suggestion and ask a mod to flag our discussion as no longer needed.
